# How can we find $Cov(X(s), X(t))$ for a compound poisson process?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

If I assume that $X(t)$ is a compound poisson process, how can it be found what $Cov(X(s), X(t))$ is? I have seen this over and over in books, but they only state it as fact. It is stated to be $\lambda E[Y]min(s,t)$, but I cannot quite seem to get the computation down. Many thanks if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: What is $Y$?  If it refers to the distribution of the size of the jumps, then your formula should involve the expectation of $Y^2$.  After all, for $s=t$ it must reduce to [the variance of $X(t)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process#Properties_of_the_compound_Poisson_process), which is $\lambda t E[Y^2]$.

Answer (score 6):

$Cov(X(s),X(t))$ are overlapping in timeline...

So now, we need to get it non-overlapping in timeline.

For $s<t$,
$Cov(X(s),X(t))=Cov(X(s),X(t)-X(s)+X(s))=Cov(X(s),X(t)-X(s))+Cov(X(s),X(s))=\lambda{s}E(Y^2)$

Now here, "$Cov(X(s),X(t)-X(s))+Cov(X(s),X(s))$" see first term is independent so equals zero, second term is variance at timeline 's'.

For $t<s$.... It will be
$Cov(X(t),X(s))=Cov(X(t),X(s)-X(t)+X(t))=Cov(X(t),X(s)-X(t))+Cov(X(t),X(t))=\lambda{t}E(Y^2)$

Hence, consider $min(s,t)$

Note:-as @whuber's comment says y is not defined here, Y considered as size of individual output.